# Finding the critical points of a map on the torus

Tags: differential-topology

Consider the $2$-torus $T$ obtained by revolving about the $z$-axis the circle $(x-2)^2+z^2=1$. I want to find the critical points of the map $f:T\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y,z)=x$.

The equation of $T$ is given by $(r-2)^2+z^2=1$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. We need to compose $f$ with a diffeomorphism (parametrization) to see the critical points.

One parametrization would be $\phi:\Bbb{R}^2\to T$ defined by $\phi(y,z)=\left(\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{z^2+y^2}-2)^2},y,z\right)$. $\phi$ parametrizes some regions of $T$.

Now look at the map $f\circ\phi:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}, (y,z)\to\sqrt{1-(\sqrt{z^2+y^2}-2)^2}$. And $$d(f\circ\phi)=\left(\frac{-z(\sqrt{z^2+y^2}-2)^2}{...},\frac{-y(\sqrt{z^2+y^2}-2)^2}{...}\right)$$

So this gradient loses rank when both coordinates are $0$. This occurs when either $z=y=0$ or $\sqrt{z^2+y^2}=2$. **But I can see only one critical point here, intuitively there are four. How do I find the rest of them?**

Comment: If you want to maximize or minimize $f$, you can show that the function $f$ attains its maximum at $(3,0,0)$ and minimum at $(-3,0,0)$

Comment: Seems like Lagrange multipliers would be an easier way to solve this problem, given that you are specifying the torus as the vanishing of an equation.